# How to model Friendship relationships

Tags: mysql, database-design, relationships, table-structure

I have been trying to figure out how to do this, and even with looking at other examples, I can't get it figured out, so maybe I can get some personalized help.

I've got two tables, `users_status` and `friendships`.

In the `users_status` table I have a field `userid`, and several others.
In the `friendships` table, I have the fields `request_to`,`request_from`, and `friendship_status`.

Basically what I want to do is get all of the status posts by the current user AND those who are friends of the current user (which I can specify in my PHP using a $userid variable).

Here's an example of the `friendships` table structure.  When a friend request is sent, the userid of the sender and receiver are placed in the table, with a friendship_status of 0.  When the request is accepted, the friendship_status is set to 1 and those two are now friends.

```
friendship_id   request_from    request_to  friendship_status
1               111248          111249      1
2               111209          111249      1
3               111209          111248      0
11              111209          111259      1
5               111252          111209      1
12              111261          111209      1
```

I realize this may not even be the best structure for determining friendships, especially since the site is relationship based and having to check for friendship connections will be a frequently used thing.

Would it perhaps be better to have two separate tables for `friend_requests` and `friendships`?  If so, how would I structure/manage the `friendships` table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a table join (e.g. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) to find all of the requests.

Actually you can use a subquery here:

```
SELECT * FROM users_status WHERE userid = "$userid" 
    OR userid in (SELECT request_to   FROM friendships where request_from = "$userid" AND friendship_status = 1)
    OR userid in (SELECT request_from FROM friendships where request_to   = "$userid" AND friendship_status = 1)
```

replace `$userid` with your user id

Comment: I realize that JOIN is an option, and I tried it, but I don't know how to get it to work with my specific situation.  That's why I posted the question.  I need more personalized help with this one.

Comment: @vertigoelectric actually you don;t need a join -- a subquery will suffice.  I updated my response

Comment: If a user requests the current user his friendships, and the current user accepts, then this query won't work right because that user won't be returned as a friend. Am I correct?

Comment: @MostyMostacho yes you would need to check the other case as well, which is a similar subquery.  updating response

Comment: @Foo Bah, I did try a subquery, too.  I tried your example, but it doesn't seem to properly check to see if the userid is in the request_to OR request_from.  I tested it as userA who sent a request to userB, who accepted it.  userA can see status posts from himself and the friend, but userB cannot see status posts from userA, who sent him the friend request even though they are both friends.  I swapped `request_to` and `request_from` in your example, and then userA could no longer see posts by userB, an expected reversal (but userB could still see both, which was strange).

Comment: @MostyMostacho, looks like you made the point more quickly than I could.  I look forward to Foo Bah's updated example.

Comment: @vertigoelectric you need two subqueries -- check my response

Comment: @FooBah, it works perfectly!  Thank you so much!  Using two subqueries in a linear fashion like that should have been obvious.  Thanks!

Comment: @FooBah, would you mind one more thing?  I have another function that gets the same data but only if it is newer than what's already showing on the page.  I need to add `statuspostdate > '$latestposttimestamp'` to the whole thing.  I've tried different ways of doing it but nothing is working so far.  I'll keep trying and let you know if I figure it out, but just in case, would you mind helping me with it?

Comment: @vertigoelectric can you ask a separate question, and in that question put the code for the function

Comment: @FooBah, **UPDATE** Never mind.  I'm an idiot.  I forgot to define `$userid` on that specific page!  No wonder nothing was coming up. I got it working now!

Answer (score 3):

The simplest schema I can think of is:

```
PENDING_FRIENDSHIPS(request_from, request_to)
FRIENDSHIPS(request_from, request_to)
```

I also removed the ID because both fields on both tables will be compound primary keys (request_from, request_to).

To get all friends from the current user just run:

```
select * from friendships
where $currentUser = request_from OR $currentUser = request_to
```

This would return both columns and you would have to remove in PHP the current user.

Another way to get all friends from this schema is to run a UNION:

```
select request_from from friendships
where request_to = $currentUser
UNION
select request_to from friendships
where request_from = $currentUser
```

The drawback of this solution is that you're running 2 selects